# Couldn't display buttons on hovering

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to display a set of buttons when user hover over a particular button (Settings), I was able to do it when user hover over the current div element hide the particular button(Settings) and show the other buttons,

```
<div class="md-card container">
    <p matLine><b>{{message.artifactId}}</b></p>
    <p matLine>
        {{message.groupId}} &nbsp;&nbsp; {{message.version}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right settingsbtn">
            <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
        </button>
        <a routerLink="/baseline-errors/{{message.id}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn">
                <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
            </button>
        </a>
        <button *ngIf="isScanning" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right spaceTest listbtn"
                (click)="rescanBaseline(message)">
            <i class="material-icons">refresh</i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn"
                (click)="deleteBaseline(message)">
            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn"
                (click)="editBaseline(message)"><i
                class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </button>
    </p>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.listbtn {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.container:hover .listbtn {
    opacity: 1;
}

.settingsbtn {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.container:hover .settingsbtn {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This code works for div element but I want to change it to when user hover over the settings button rest will be shown, So I changed the code as this.

```
<div class="md-card container">
    <p matLine><b>{{message.artifactId}}</b></p>
    <p matLine>
        {{message.groupId}} &nbsp;&nbsp; {{message.version}}
        <span class="sd">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right settingsbtn">
        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
        </button>
        <a routerLink="/baseline-errors/{{message.id}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn">
                <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
            </button>
        </a>
        <button *ngIf="isScanning" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right spaceTest listbtn"
                (click)="rescanBaseline(message)">
            <i class="material-icons">refresh</i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn"
                (click)="deleteBaseline(message)">
            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn"
                (click)="editBaseline(message)"><i
                class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </button>
        </span>
    </p>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.listbtn {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.sd:hover .listbtn {
    opacity: 1;
}

.settingsbtn {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.sd:hover .settingsbtn {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

But it didn't work, what is the mistake I am making here?

**EDIT**

I want to display the settings button initially and when user hovers over settings button it should be hidden and other buttons should be visible but when user hovers over other buttons initially it shouldn't show those buttons. My current code snippet will work as when user hovers over any button either settings or hidden it will show the  buttons.

Comment: what's your requirement, it's working correctly

Comment: Try to *reproduce* the issue *here* using a *Code Snippet* for user-friendly troubleshooting.

Comment: @veera I want to show other buttons only when user hovers over the Settings button, currently it works when user hovers over the card(div).

Answer (score 1):

your code is working correctly, is this you want?

```css
.listbtn {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.sd .settingsbtn:hover ~ .listbtn {
    opacity: 1;
}

.settingsbtn {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.sd .settingsbtn:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="sd">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right settingsbtn">
<i class="material-icons">settings</i>
</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn">
<i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn">
<i class="material-icons">refresh</i>
</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn">
<i class="material-icons">delete</i>
</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn">
<i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Its working here, But I couldn't figure out why its not working in my code.

Comment: It is not working as I told asked, I want to show other buttons only when user hovers over the setting button. But in this case it will show even when user hovers over the hidden buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css it will works

```
.listbtn {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.settingsbtn:hover ~ .listbtn,.settingsbtn:hover + a .listbtn {
    opacity: 1;
}

.settingsbtn {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.settingsbtn:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```css
.listbtn {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.settingsbtn:hover ~ .listbtn,.settingsbtn:hover + a .listbtn {
    opacity: 1;
}

.settingsbtn {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.settingsbtn:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="md-card container">
    <p matLine><b>{{message.artifactId}}</b></p>
    <p matLine>
        {{message.groupId}} &nbsp;&nbsp; {{message.version}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right settingsbtn">
        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
        </button>
        <a routerLink="/baseline-errors/{{message.id}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn">
                <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
            </button>
        </a>
        <button *ngIf="isScanning" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right spaceTest listbtn"
                (click)="rescanBaseline(message)">
            <i class="material-icons">refresh</i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn"
                (click)="deleteBaseline(message)">
            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right listbtn"
                (click)="editBaseline(message)"><i
                class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </button>
    </p>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</div>
```

Comment: Still its not working, I think these styles are overriding in somewhere, I will check it. Now settings button is hidden but other buttons are not shown.

Comment: Okey check at your side.